# how can i find the index of an item array, to find if an item is in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, greasemonkey

I'm new to scripting and I was writing a script to find if a value is in an array.

/*html*/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>account # a</p>

</body>
</html>
```

/*javascript*/

```
var cid = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

var res = cid.split(" ");

var customerid=res[2];

var abs=['a','b','c'];

var para = document.createElement("P");

var node = document.createTextNode("'"+customerid+"'");

para.appendChild(node);

document.body.appendChild(para); 

var c=document.getElementsByTagName("P")[1].childNodes[0].data;

window.alert(abs.indexOf(c));
```

the alert window is showing the index as -1. my plan was to use the following function if i can get the above code to get the correct index.

```
function check(){

if (abs.indexOf(c)>=0){

window.alert("item is in array");
}
}

check();
```

Comment: The `.indexOf()` function returns `-1` when the searched-for item is *not* in the array.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the problem.

when we run window.alert(c); it prints out  'FERT54RSE3QW' which should be equal to abs[0] ?

Comment: You're adding single-quote characters around the value.

Comment: won't it work with single quotes? how can i add double quotes?

Comment: Why are you adding those quotes at all? The problem is that you're searching the array, whose strings do not contain quotes, for a string that does have the added quotes. Try just `document.createTextNode(customerid);` without adding any quotes.

Comment: thank you @Pointy, that worked.

I was unable to solve the problem on a bigger page. i tried this method in that page but didn't work. so I made a simple html page to test the script.

I'll try on the main page again. if it dosen't work then the issue should be something else.

Answer (score 1):

`.indexOf()` will return `-1` when the item is NOT in the array.  This is because if the item is in the first index of the array, it's at index `0` since arrays are zero-based.

For your check function, as mentioned above, `0` means that the element was found in the array in the first position.  So you'll want to check if `.indexOf()` doesn't return -1 instead of greater than 0:

```
function check() {
if (abs.indexOf(c) !== -1){
    window.alert("item is in array");
  }
}
```

You could also use the `~` shortcut:

```
function check() {
if (~abs.indexOf(c)){
    window.alert("item is in array");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the single-quote characters that are added to the value when the new `<p>` element is created.

Comment: 1. I already split the string in 2nd line of javascript....

2. In the third line assigned the value of FERT54RSE3QW to var customerid....

3. and then created a new html element so that i can add 'quotes' to 'FERT54RSE3QW' . I didn't know how else to do this.......

4. Then I assigned var c to 'FERT54RSE3QW' so that window.alert(abs.indexOf(c)); would be equal to window.alert(abs.indexOf('FERT54RSE3QW' ));...........

but unfortunately it wont recognize it

Comment: won't it work with single quotes? how can i add double quotes?

i cant understand why ---window.alert(['FERT54RSE3QW','WEHUEUWE767','QWEWQWEQW'].indexOf(c));--- returns -1 when--- window.alert(c);----returns 'FERT54RSE3QW' and -------window.alert(['FERT54RSE3QW','WEHUEUWE767','QWEWQWEQW'].indexOf('FERT54RSE3QW'));--- returns 0

Comment: The quotes inside a string and the quotes that define an array element are different.  If your array has ['a', 'b'], then you have elements `a` and `b`, not `'a'` and `'b'`.